# Port forwarding to VPN client

Tags: vpn, routing, port-forwarding, iptables, tomato

I have a router on Tomato (shibby) running an OpenVPN server (with TAP; interface is `tap21` on the router). Various resources (including some workstations) are physically connected to `eth0` on this router. I have another physical device across the country which is running nginx and other services. Now, I know this isn't a great topographical setup, but unalterable circumstances require that the device running nginx *must* be a client of the router VPN and all of this device's inbound traffic and outbound traffic on ports 80 and 443 must be tunnelled through this VPN connection.

So basically, what needs to happen is:

1. example.com resolves to IP of WAN on the router
2. router forwards ports 80 and 443 through `tap21` interface to nginx server
3. nginx server response comes back through `tap21` and is routed back through WAN

The #2 part is what I'm having trouble with.

The server is currently able to communicate with other devices on the subnet (able to ping other resources on the VPN as well as resources physically connected to `eth0` on the router) and can access the internet through the VPN. However, I've been unable to forward ports from WAN to the server's address on the VPN. The first attempt I made was simply trying the port forwarding GUI in Tomato (but this seems not to work for IPs on the VPN, only those on `eth0` or `wlan0`). When that didn't work, I tried adding iptables rules, but as I'm still largely uncomfortable with iptables I've only been able to find snippets from other answers for questions that don't really relate to this weird and problematic networking setup. Here's what I'm trying (using 10000 as a test port with `nc` listening):

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.12.53:10000
iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.12.53 -p tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
```

However, I can't figure out what's happening to packets being re-routed in this way--they're certainly not reaching the server. Essentially, my question is how can I forward inbound connections on particular ports to a particular device on a VPN? Outbound traffic on ports 80 and 443 from other resources on the router's `eth0` must, of course, not be affected.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tinkering, I figured it out (although I welcome any comments that could explain *why* this is working). Firstly, not having a `POSTROUTING` rule was, apparently, causing the server to discard the packets. By examining the `iptables` rules that Tomato creates through the GUI, I created similar entries for `WANPREROUTING`, `wanin`, and `INPUT`; I'm not entirely sure why the `INPUT` rule is necessary; perhaps it could be removed and the `-m` flag could be added to `wanin`?

```
iptables -t nat -I WANPREROUTING -i vlan2 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination {SERVER_IP}:80
iptables -I wanin -d {SERVER_IP} -i vlan2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -i vlan2 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j shlimit
```

The Tomato GUI does not create `POSTROUTING` rules automatically, so I had to do that as well:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p tcp -d {SERVER_IP} --dport 80 -o tun22 \! -s {GATEWAY_IP} -j SNAT --to-source {GATEWAY_IP}
```

I did sets of rules like this for ports 80 and 443, and I can now access the server through the VPN from the internet.